# Joomla component title in admin menu doesn't get translated

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hello fellow programmers.

I'm developing a component for a customer in Joomla 2.5.6.
I have built my manifest XML file by looking at some of the other components manifest file (and Joomlas own docs).

The issue I'm having is when looking in the administration menu the link text doesn't get translated but rather it gets turned into "com-mycomponent". 
So this looks like a problem with the language files. But here comes the weird part, when I click the link it opens the page just fine but when I then look in the menu, it now displays the translated menu item text.

So my guess is that Joomla only loads the language files when that component is in use, which would make sense.

But how do get Joomla to translate the menu item when not using that component.

Heres my *mycomponent.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade">

    <name>My Component</name>
    <!-- The following elements are optional and free of formatting constraints -->
    <creationDate>April 2016</creationDate>
    <author>My name</author>
    <authorEmail>My email</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://www.mywebsite.com</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright My company</copyright>
    <license>N/A</license>
    <!--  The version string is recorded in the components table -->
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <!-- The description is optional and defaults to the name -->
    <description>Description of the Hello World component ...</description>

    <media destination="com_mycomponent" folder="media">
        <folder>icons</folder>
    </media>

    <administration>
        <!-- Administration Menu Section -->
        <menu link="option=com_mycomponent" img="../media/com_mycomponent/icons/dollar-iconx16.png" view="queue">COM_MYCOMPONENT</menu>

        <!-- Administration Main File Copy Section -->
        <!-- Note the folder attribute: This attribute describes the folder
            to copy FROM in the package to install therefore files copied
            in this section are copied from /admin/ in the package -->
        <files folder="admin">
            <!-- Admin Main File Copy Section -->
            <filename>com_mycomponent.php</filename>
            <filename>controller.php</filename>
            <folder>controllers</folder>
            <folder>views</folder>
            <folder>language</folder>
        </files>

        <languages folder="admin">
            <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.com_mycomponent.ini</language>
            <language tag="da-DK">language/da-DK/da-DK.com_mycomponent.ini</language>
        </languages>
    </administration>

</extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files) where is well-explained how to use language files, for administrator's menu you need a .sys.ini language file:

> Joomla! extension's must also specify a sys.ini file which is used
>
> a. during the extension's installation, to allow localising the
>   post-installation messages,
>   **b. to build the administrator Components
>   menu**, c. to localise component parameters and menu parameters d. and
>   in the Extension Manager->Manage.

For joomla related questions you can use [joomla.stackexchange.com](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Thank you! Must have been a rookie mistake.
Good to know about the Joomla stackexchange site.